# C++ OpenGL Cube not showing up on screen

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I have been attempting to use OpenGL with C++ lately and I have come a cross a problem when trying to render a cube with lighting, but it doesn't appear I believe this is due to some kinda of clipping error.

Here is my code. The initialization function:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); //Enable lighting
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0); //Enable light #0
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1); //Enable light #1
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE); //Automatically normalize normals
```

and here is the draw code

```
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -8.0f);

//Add ambient light
GLfloat ambientColor[] = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f}; //Color (0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientColor);

//Add positioned light
GLfloat lightColor0[] = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f}; //Color (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
GLfloat lightPos0[] = {4.0f, 0.0f, 8.0f, 1.0f}; //Positioned at (4, 0, 8)
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor0);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos0);

//Add directed light
GLfloat lightColor1[] = {0.5f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f}; //Color (0.5, 0.2, 0.2)
//Coming from the direction (-1, 0.5, 0.5)
GLfloat lightPos1[] = {-1.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor1);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, lightPos1);

glRotatef(Rotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

//Front
glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
//glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.5f, -1.0f, 1.5f);
//glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, -1.0f, 1.5f);
//glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, 1.5f);
//glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.5f, 1.0f, 1.5f);

//Right
glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
//glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, -1.0f, -1.5f);
//glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, -1.5f);
//glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, 1.5f);
//glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, -1.0f, 1.5f);

//Back
glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
//glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.5f, -1.0f, -1.5f);
//glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.5f, 1.0f, -1.5f);
//glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, -1.5f);
//glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(1.5f, -1.0f, -1.5f);

//Left
glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
//glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.5f, -1.0f, -1.5f);
//glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.5f, -1.0f, 1.5f);
//glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.5f, 1.0f, 1.5f);
//glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(-1.5f, 1.0f, -1.5f);

glEnd();

        SwapBuffers(hDC);

        Sleep (1);
```

---

after following the advice of Keith i attempted to use the gluLookAt like this:

```
void gluLookAt  (   10.0 , 10.0 , 10.0 , 1.5, -1.0, 1.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
```

but I get an error

```
|74|error: variable or field `gluLookAt' declared void|
```

Comment: NeHe has a nice tutorial for beginners: http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=02

Comment: ... i dont have a problem with my rendering code... plus that tutorial is 2d....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your edit: `gluLookAt` is a function just like `glVertex3f` and such. Therefore invoke it by just calling:

```
gluLookAt(10.0 , 10.0 , 10.0 , 1.5, -1.0, 1.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
```

Note that there is no `void` involved in this line of code!

What the compiler sees if there is a  `void` in front of this line is a variable declaration named `gluLookAt` of type `void` initialized (constructed) with a bunch of doubles.

Comment: lol yeah... the example i looked at was in C...i forgot to update this thread but i found my error..thanks for your help anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

You may need to define the *projection matrix*.

This can be done with, for example, [gluLookAt()](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/gluLookAt.3G.html)

Comment: Yes, but `glFrustum()` or `gluPerspective()` should be used to define the projection matrix. `gluLookAt()` should be used on the modelview matrix!